# How to change Emacs struct indents from 4 to 2 spaces

Tags: c++, emacs, struct

```
;; C++ Mode
(c-set-offset 'access-label '-2)
(c-set-offset 'inclass '4)
(setq c-default-style "k&r"
      c-basic-offset 2)
```

That is my C++ configuration. I want Emacs to indent structs with 2 spaces, just like it is indenting functions, if/while/for blocks, but currently it does this:

```
struct plane {
    //4 spaces'?
};
```

However, it does this:

```
typedef car {
  //2 spaces!
}
```

I tried using `c-mode` and `c++-mode`. When I do `M-x c-set-offset` inside a struct (where it is currently indenting with 4 spaces), it detects it as `topmost-intro` (0 spaces), even on C++ mode.

Basically, I want inside-structs to be indented with 2 spaces instead of 4 spaces as it is right now. (GNU Emacs 24.2.1)

Comment: I have no idea of emacs configs, but I am wondering what for you use `(c-set-offset 'inclass '4)`

Comment: Well, actually, Emacs was detecting things inside structs as classes, so setting inclass to 2 fixes this problem. However, I need 'inclass '4 because I want classes to look like this: https://gist.github.com/davidgomes/5911a59d099a826a3c70

Comment: are you sure that emacs can distinguish between classes and structs (for indentation purposes)?

Comment: In C++, a `struct` is a class (though not a `class`) whose default access level is `public`. Most probably emacs has no way to differentiate between `class` and `struct`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove your configuration and start with

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(c-basic-offset 2))
```

This sets all indentation at 2 spaces.
Then you can improve from there on.

You can set `c-offsets-alist` for example, to customize indentation for various elements. Or `c-hanging-braces-alist` to configure, where your braces should be set, on the same or at the next line. And so on.

If you have installed CC Mode info files, you can browse through it with

<kbd>Ctrl-h i m</kbd><kbd>CC Mode</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

CC Mode doesn't distinguish between `class` and `struct`, for both the syntactic element is `inclass`. You can have a different indentation based on struct only with a [Custom Line-Up Function](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ccmode.html#Custom-Line_002dUp)

```
(defun my/c-lineup-inclass (langelem)
  (let ((inclass (assoc 'inclass c-syntactic-context)))
    (if (not inclass)
        0
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (c-langelem-pos inclass))
        (if (looking-at "struct") 0 '+)))))
```

This function looks, if you are inside a `class` or `struct` or outside and returns an indentation level accordingly. You can then use this in your `c-offsets-alist`

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(c-offsets-alist (quote ((access-label . 0)
                           (topmost-intro . my/c-lineup-inclass)))))
```